# Mingw-w64 - printf does not work

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, console, mingw, mingw-w64

First I wanted to modificate ffplay according to my requirments. Then I noticed that original ffplay from my build can't play some video files, but it didn't write any message to console. Then I noticed that ffmpeg also don't write any usage message when I run it without params. But it works. **If I run it from terminal it's like running asynchronously!** The terminal just shows next row. I mean it asks for a next command. But the `ffmpeg` process is visible in task manager and it writes the output video file what I had requested!

I created following souce file. I have modified the Makefile. So it have built the exe-file works just the same way. I have no idea how it can be.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "cmdutils.h"

const char program_name[] = "hello";
const int program_birth_year = 2013;

void show_help_default(const char *opt, const char *arg)
{
    printf("zxcvbnm\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("1234567890\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And after that I created **real** hello world app with MinGW-w64 and qmake **without eny extra libs**. And its printf does not work.

**I want to prevent this behavior.**

**I want to make printf working in traditional manner.**

How I build FFmpeg:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/lib/pkgconfig/ \
SDL_CONFIG=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/bin/sdl-config \
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/lib" \
  --extra-cflags="-I/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/include" \
  --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32-  \
  --pkg-config=pkg-config   --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-outdev=sdl --enable-shared --disable-static \
  --disable-doc --disable-manpages --disable-podpages

make
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

By some reason you must visibly specify you make console app.

In qmake helloworld:

```
CONFIG   += console
```

In FFmpeg's `configure` script it's an extra-ldflag `console`:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/lib/pkgconfig/ \
SDL_CONFIG=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/bin/sdl-config \
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/lib -Wl,-subsystem,console" \
  --extra-cflags="-I/home/developer/workspace/MinGW32fs/include" \
  --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32-  \
  --pkg-config=pkg-config   --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-outdev=sdl --enable-shared --disable-static \
  --disable-doc --disable-manpages --disable-podpages
```